# Determining total blocks solved

Tags: blockchain, block, altcoin

How do you determine the total blocks solved among all clients in the source code of an Altcoin? Is there a file in the code that can be viewed to see how many blocks have been solved in the meta data? How can this be determined or where can one look in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the current blockheight of any coin, you will need to pull data from the network itself. The source code that runs a node for any coin will not include this information.

A full node will download the blockchain history, so your node could then report the current blockheight back to you. The source code basically contains instructions telling your computer *how* to do this, but the explicit block height is not contained within the source code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response... I forked a coin and have the main server node a VPS where other nodes connect. Is this information on the .mycoin directory on the VPS? Thank you so much again.

Comment: You'll want to query your node for the current blockheight. You'll need to check the docs for the software you forked to find exactly how this is done.